# Android Studio - ¿Cómo comprobar si un text-view está seleccionado?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

**Descripción**

Lo bueno de los check boxes o radio buttons, es que tienen un método que permite saber si éstos están seleccionados **.isChecked()**. Con este método, fácilmente podemos saber si se presionaron o no. Ahora el tema es: **¿Y si quiero lograr esto mismo con texto**?

**Adjunto foto de mi layout**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Problema:**

Como se puede ver en la imágen, mi layout de tipo reloj da la opción de elegir si el horario a seleccionar va a ser **AM** o **PM**. Estos dos, son text views. Lo que me gustaría lograr es que al tocar un número (que representan las horas del día), la app detecte si se seleccionó "am" o "pm" y transforme dicho número a su equivalente.

**Ejemplo:**

Si el usuario toca "PM" y luego toca el número 1, la app devolverá un "13:00" representando a la 1 pm.

¿Cómo lo hago?

**Gracias por leer!**

Comment: El problema es que un checkbox o un radio button, una vez pulsado, guardan su estado (pulsado o despulsado), pero un textview no. Podrías como te han dicho en la respuesta implementar el click, pero eso no cambiará la vista ni mostrará seleccionado uno a menos que lo programes tú. Te recomiendo mejor que uses controles Switch para esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes agregar un evento onclick a cada textView y guardar en una variable un valor booleano que represente el textView al que se le dio click.

Algo así:

```
private boolean isAM;

textViewAM.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        this.isAM = true;
    } 
});

textViewPM.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        this.isAM = false;
    } 
});

public String getHora(){
  return this.isAM ? "hora am " : "hora pm";
}
```

Comment: Me funcionó. Muchas graciias!